# Не копируется .exe файл

Tags: golang

Все директории и файлы правильно указаны, у меня создается файл x.exe но не несет в себе информации то есть он равняется 0 байтам. Собственно говоря ничего то и не копируется, но только вот почему?

Код:

```
src, _ := os.Open("C:\\File\\x.exe")
defer src.Close()

dst, _ := os.Create("C:\\File\\New\\x.exe")
defer dst.Close()

_, err = io.Copy(src, dst) // check first var for number of bytes copied
err = dst.Sync()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error")
}
```

`x.exe` весит 2 мегабайта и должен успешно копироваться в `C:\\File\\New`. Но этого не происходит. Ошибок тоже программа не выдает.

Comment: Что в Go с экранированием спецсимволов?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов изменил, все ровно не копируется

Comment: @JackAnderson а вы не перепутали порядок аргументов io.Copy?

Comment: @ЕгорБанин спасибо, оказалось что да!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`func Copy(dst Writer, src Reader) (written int64, err error)`

Другой порядок параметров.

И добавьте обработку ошибок.